# Flexigrid columns groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

Has anyone tried to set a common header text of more than one column in flexigrid?

For example: I would like to label/group second and third columns with text "Received" and fourth and last column wit text "Sent".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#flex1").flexigrid({
    url: 'data.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    colModel : [
        {display: 'Ports', name : 'port', width : 40, sortable : true},
        {display: 'Bytes', name : 'rx_bytes', width : 40, sortable : true},
        {display: 'Packets', name : 'rx_pkts', width : 40, sortable : true},
        {display: 'Bytes', name : 'tx_bytes', width : 40, sortable : true},
        {display: 'Packets', name : 'tx_pkts', width : 40, sortable : true},
        ],
    usepager: false,
    useRp: true,
    width: 626,
    height: 200
});
```

Such a functionality is satisfied by AdvancedDataGrid in Flex (e.g. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/simpleColumnGroupbwg.png) where you can create GroupColumns. Does anyone know if such a functionality is supported by Flexigrid?

Comment: Hi , I am not flexigrid user , but i had seen this feature in datatables , its really great http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel:[]
```

Sets just the names and the style of the headers.What's important is the data you'll receive from

```
url: 'data.xml'
```

So the grid names play no role.

For more information on flexigrid check this [http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids](http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/)